# Gradle automatically include Appcompat V7 in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, behavior

I have just started to use Android Studio, migrating from Eclipse. 
 I encountered a problem right on the start: I want to create an application project for android 3.0 and up. However Gradle automatically include `Appcompat_v7` in their dependencies, and the default java code extends `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`. 
 I tried to things by delete the dependencies but everything just went berserk, so I am here to ask you guys what is a possible fix for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say 'deleting dependencies', what do you mean? Did you do that in the build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes I did that in the build.gradle file. Is it the correct way to do that? I tried but there is that error `R not found` or something.

Comment: That is the correct way. I started my own project with AS 0.8.1, with no activity (blank project), and then added the support library later - all worked fine. AS is in beta though, so glitches are expected. Can you try with a blank project and/or tell what you mean by it went berserk?

Comment: I will try, if it is the correct way to do so I'll tell you so you can make an answer about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I thought you were using eclipse. But let my answer stay here so that someone using eclipse may see the solution.

When creating the project please make sure you unchceck the "Create Activity" checkbox. This way you can prevent Appcompat_v7 to be added automatically.

[image]